# Creating a Dynamic Form in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, model

i'm currently working on a project that would have a database of reports of a scam. In the report section of the website I have a form, but I want anyone to be able to add multiple profiles with a click of a button. For example:

```
Nickname field: xyz
Steam profile: x
[ + ] <- button for adding more profiles, which when pressed would look something like this:
Nickname field: xyz
Steam profile: x
Steam profile 2: y [ Delete ]
[ + ]
```

I was looking into FormSets and Inline Formsets, but nothing turned up that would match this specific need, aswell as did not answer the question regarding storing the results of the form. 
How would I go about creating the form for this?
How would I store the multiple results of `Steam profile` to my object that has a `steam_profile = models.CharField`? 
My current model:

```python
class Scammer(models.Model):
    #Basic information for display
    steam_id_64 = models.CharField(max_length=17, default='00000000000000000')
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=64, default='Nickname')
    steam_profile = models.CharField(max_length=512, default='https://www.steamcommunity.com')
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    proof = models.TextField(default='')

    #Date created var for ordering
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nickname

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('dashboard-home')
```

My view:

```python
class ScammerCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Scammer_Unapproved
    template_name='dashboard/report.html'
    fields = ['nickname', 'steam_id_64', 'steam_profile', 'description', 'proof']
```

My template:

```html
{% block content %}
    <div class="report-scammer">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Report a scammer</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div>
                <button type="submit">Report</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the profiles as the **Builtin Django User model** or maintain a separate model with a link to the inbuilt User model. Now the scam report form can have the option to be linked to Multiple User accounts by using **ManytoMany relationship field**. check the below official documentation page,

[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/][1]